# How to use exec_query with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a query and am using `exec_query` with binds to avoid potential SQL injection. However, I am running into an issue when trying to check that an id is in an array.

```sql
SELECT JSON_AGG(agg_date)
FROM (
 SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3, t3.col4, t4.col7, t4.col8, t5.col5, t5.col6
 FROM t1
 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
 JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.t3_id
 JOIN t4 ON t2.is = t4.t2_id
 JOIN t5 ON t3.id = t5.t3_id
  
 WHERE t2.id IN ($1) AND t4.id = $2
) agg_data
```

this gives an error of `invalid input syntax for integer: '1,2,3,4,5'`

And `SELECT ... WHERE t.id = ANY($1)` gives `ERROR:  malformed array literal: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

If I add the curly braces around the bind variable I get  `invalid input syntax for integer: "$1"`

Here is the way I'm using `exec_query`

```rb
connection.exec_query(<<~EOQ, "-- CUSTOM SQL --", [[nil, array_of_ids], [nil, model_id]], prepare: true)
  SELECT ... WHERE t.id IN ($1)
EOQ
```

I have tried with plain interpolation but that throws brakeman errors about sql injection so I can't use that way :(

Any help on being able to make this check is greatly appreciated. And if `exec_query` is the wrong way to go about this, I'm definitely down to try other things :D

In my class, I am using AR's internal sql injection prevention to search for the first bind variable ids, then plucking the ids and joining into a string for the sql query. I am doing the same for the other bind variable, finding the object and using that id. Just as a further precaution. So by the time the user inputs are used for the query, they've been through AR already. It's a brakeman scan that it throwing the error. I ahve a meeting on monday with our security team about this, but wanted to check here also :D

Comment: Can you show us the actual query? Its hard to actually provide a decent answer with only a fraction of the picture? Is it something that you can compose with the AR query interface and Arel instead of a string?

Comment: I don't think AR would be as performant, and I don't really need any one specific model. I updated the question to show a base of what I'm trying to do. I need json agg data and don't think AR would be able to do it or as performantly as raw sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Rails do the sanitization for you:

```rb
ar = [1,2,8,9,100,800]

MyModel.where(id: ar)
```

your concern for sql injection suggests that ar is derived from user input. It's superfluous, but maybe want to make sure it's a list of integers. `ar = user_ar.map(&:to_i)`.

```rb
# with just Rails sanitization
ar = "; drop table users;" # sql injection

MyModel.where(id: ar)

# query is:
# SELECT `my_models`.* from `my_models` WHERE `my_models`.`id` = NULL;

# or
ar = [1,2,8,100,"; drop table users;"]

MyModel.where(id: ar)

# query is
# SELECT `my_models`.* from `my_models` WHERE `my_models`.`id` in (1,2,8,100);
```

Rails has got you covered!

Comment: I know about ARs built in SQL injection preventsion.  I'll update the question, but I have a select that I think is a little too complex for AR. Plus I think as I don't need actual AR objects from the db, I feel the raw sql is better performance wise.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was using AR to santize the inputs :P I was getting the collection of ids, finding the AR object collection, then rejoining the ids into a string for the raw query. I was hoping to find a way I didn't have to do that. But I had a meeting with my security person at work and they informed me that it was a false positive by brakeman, due to my preprocessing. Thanks for reinforcing my choices :D

Answer (score 0):

With Arel you could compose that query as:

```
class Aggregator

  def initialize(connection: ActiveRecord::Base.connection)
    @connection = connection
    @t1 = Arel::Table.new('t1')
    @t2 = Arel::Table.new('t2')
    @t3 = Arel::Table.new('t3')
    @t4 = Arel::Table.new('t4')
    @t5 = Arel::Table.new('t5')
    @columns = [
      :col1, 
      :col2, 
      @t2[:col1], 
      @t2[:col2], 
      @t3[:col3], 
      @t3[:col4], 
      @t4[:col7], 
      @t4[:col8], 
      @t5[:col5], 
      @t5[:col6]
    ]
  end
  
  def query(t2_ids:, t4_id:)
    agg_data = t1.project(*columns)
                 .where(
                   t2[:id].in(t2_ids)
                   .and(t4[:id].eq(t4_id))
                 ) 
                 .join(t2).on(t1[:id].eq(t2[:t1_id]))
                 .join(t3).on(t1[:id].eq(t3[:t1_id]))
                 .join(t4).on(t1[:id].eq(t4[:t1_id]))
                 .join(t5).on(t1[:id].eq(t5[:t1_id])) 
                 .as('agg_data')

    yield agg_data if block_given?
    t1.project('JSON_AGG(agg_data)')
      .from(agg_data)
  end

  def exec_query(t2_ids:, t4_id:)
    connection.exec_query(
      query(t2_ids: t2_ids, t4_id: t4_id),
      "-- CUSTOM SQL --"
    )
  end

  private

  attr_reader :connection, :t1, :t2, :t3, :t4, :t5, :columns

end
```

Of course it would be a lot cleaner to just setup some models so that you can do `t1.joins(:t2, :t3, :t4, ...)`. Your performance concerns are pretty unfounded as ActiveRecord has quite a few methods to query and get raw results instead of model instances.

Using bind variables for a `WHERE IN ()` condition is somewhat problematic as you have to use a matching number of bind variables to the number of elements in the list:

```
irb(main):118:0> T1.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
  T1 Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "t1s".* FROM "t1s" WHERE "t1s"."id" IN (?, ?, ?) /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?
```

Which means that you have to know the number of bind variables beforehand when preparing the query. As a hacky workaround you can use some creative typecasting to get Postgres to split a comma seperated string into an array:

```
class Aggregator

  # ...
  
  def query
    agg_data = t1.project(*columns)
                 .where(
                   t2[:id].eq('any (string_to_array(?)::int[])')
                   .and(t4[:id].eq(Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new('$2')))
                 ) 
                 .join(t2).on(t1[:id].eq(t2[:t1_id]))
                 .join(t3).on(t1[:id].eq(t3[:t1_id]))
                 .join(t4).on(t1[:id].eq(t4[:t1_id]))
                 .join(t5).on(t1[:id].eq(t5[:t1_id])) 
                 .as('agg_data')

    yield agg_data if block_given?
    t1.project('JSON_AGG(agg_data)')
      .from(agg_data)
  end

  def exec_query(t2_ids:, t4_id:)
    connection.exec_query(
      query,
      "-- CUSTOM SQL --"
      [
        [t2_ids.map {|id| Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(id) }.join(',')],
        [t4_id]
      ]
    )
  end

  # ...
end
```